# Email file only after it contains 20 lines

Tags: shell-script

I have recently begun working for a very small company and am in the process of trying to save them time by automating their inventory intake process of Mikrotik Routers which they put in every customers home to be used as a "Dmarc" or home wifi router. The Routers are ordered 5 boxes at a time and come in boxes of 20. Initially they have an undesirable configuration out of the box as well as out of date FirmWare.  Until I got there the company spent hours a day logging into each router and removing the out-of-the-box config and replacing it with the config that works for the company, Updating the FirmWare, then adding the device to their on the shelf inventory. I have written the following script to log into a batch of routers ( I am currently able to do 6 at a time ) and perform these actions. I need some help adding an if loop to wait for the "inventory sheet" to contain 20 lines before emailing it to be added to inventory. This script currently runs every 16 minuets... Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
echo $(date "+%F %T") : starting script >> Script_timer.log
#Scans for new Mikrotiks to configure on the office LAN
mactelnet -lB > targetsfull.inv &

# Gets PID of scanning activity
PID=$!

#wait 5 seconds
sleep 5

#end scan
kill $PID

#Grab MAC addresses from scan info into file called targetsMAC.inv
grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' targetsfull.inv > targetsMAC.inv

#Run Expect Script on every MAC address in targetsMAC.inv and adds them to CompleteRouters.inv ( Records Serial Number and MAC address of eth1 for each router and replaces factory config with company default config

/home/michael/hAPRtRMAC.sh



#Formats list of serial numbers and MAC addresses into 2 columns "serialnumber,MACaddress"
xargs -n2 < CompleteRouters.inv >> InventoryConfigsComplete.inv

#places a comma between the serial number and MAC address 
sed -i "s/ /,/g" InventoryConfigsComplete.inv

#removes Duplicate Lines and saves to new file
awk '!seen[$0]++' InventoryConfigsComplete.inv > InventoryConfigsEmail.inv
```

Kamaraj's Answer Plugs right in and works well

```
FILE_NAME=InventoryConfigsEmail.inv

NUM_OF_LINES=$(wc -l < ${FILE_NAME})

if [ "${NUM_OF_LINES}" -ge "20" ]
then
    echo "Triggering Inventory Complete Email"
    mail -s "Inventory Configs Complete" someone@gmail.com < "${FILE_NAME}"
    mv *.inv safezone/
    touch CompleteRouters.inv
    touch InventoryConfigsComplete.inv
    touch InventoryConfigsEmail.inv

else
    echo "${NUM_OF_LINES} Routers Complete" >> ChangeTheBatch.inv 
fi
echo $(date "+%F %T") :script ended >> Script_timer.log
sleep 960
done
```

Comment: Why don't you just add 20 lines and then fire the email?  If the script that is adding the lines is the same script that sends the email, it should be easy to do.

Comment: Good Point. Let me edit the question

Comment: This is beginning to look like [an XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271976) — you want to send an email for every box of routers you have configured, and your approach is to do it by counting. What if you get a box where one router is damaged to the point of inoperability? Would you reject the entire box?  or configure the 19 good ones and carry on? You might want to think about having some way to have the email triggered directly by the configuration of the last router from a box.

Comment: The routers get configured regardless. If one fails the script just moves on to the next. BUT I dont have any logging output to let me know that one failed. This would offset the sending of the email by one and send an email after the first 6 of the next box were configured. So we wouldnt know that one failed until we went to install it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this script checks the line numer of /tmp/my.log and if it's greater than or equal to 20, then it will send email

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_NAME=/tmp/my.log

NUM_OF_LINES=$(wc -l < ${FILE_NAME})

if [ "${NUM_OF_LINES}" -ge "20" ]
then
    echo "Triggering Email"
    mail -s "Log" abcd@xyz.com < "${FILE_NAME}"
else
    echo "Log file contains ${NUM_OF_LINES} lines"
fi
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I edited it to do a couple more things:
FILE_NAME=InventoryConfigsEmail.inv

NUM_OF_LINES=$(wc -l < ${FILE_NAME})

if [ "${NUM_OF_LINES}" -ge "20" ]
then
    echo "Triggering Email"
    mail -s "Inventory Configs Complete" someone@gmail.com < "${FILE_NAME}"
    mv *.inv safezone/
    touch CompleteRouters.inv
    touch InventoryConfigsComplete.inv
    touch InventoryConfigsEmail.inv

else
    echo ${NUM_OF_LINES} Routers Complete >> ChangeTheBatch.inv
    mail -s "Change the Config Batch" someone@gmail.com < ChangeTheBatch.inv
fi